# Error in repository

Tags: updates, repositories

When i try to `sudo apt update`, i get the following error:

> E: Release file for
>   http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/bionic/InRelease is not
>   valid yet (invalid for another 50min 7s). Updates for this repository
>   will not be applied. E: Release file for
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is
>   not valid yet (invalid for another 8min 17s). Updates for this
>   repository will not be applied. E: Release file for
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not
>   valid yet (invalid for another 44min 6s). Updates for this repository
>   will not be applied.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the culprit.
Just noticed my clock was wrong.
Now everything is working again...

Comment: same with me, everything is working now, thanks

Comment: i am also facing the same issue, can you tell me what you did exactly?

Comment: Corrected the time. That was it.